# Can I tokenize an SQL strings in Python?

Tags: python, sql, tokenize

I want to be able to insert a string representing a SQL query and have it output a list of tokens according to a table:[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piDLc.png) [table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHWuP.png)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcXvC.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you get better answers, please read through this guide on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For example, please describe your attempts at solving the problem, and where you are stuck.

Comment: The table is incomplete. You really need to recognise '\n' to know the end of a `--` comment.